# How I can check whether 2 databases despite being in different postgresql servers of versions are the same?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-11

I copied an existing posttgresql database from one server to another. The source of my data is a postgresql 9.6 whilst the newer server is in postgresql 11.

So I want to know how I can check that both databases have the same schema and data in a fast and easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that in a fast way.

The best you can do is to dump both databases **using `pg_dump` from v11** and compare the files with `diff`.

If you want to do that just to ensure that the migration was successful, don't. If you don't trust PostgreSQL's upgrade process, why should you trust `pg_dump`?